# Run code at midnight everyday

Tags: swift, macos, timer

I want to update status at midnight everyday. but timer is by interval. how can I set the interval by day

```
var timer = Timer()

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

// called every time interval from the timer
func timerAction() {

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a timer for this? Because a timer invalidates(gets removed) once you close your application. So it would only work if the user kept the application open from start of the timer until midnight

Comment: Just want this application can alarm in specific time. this application can start with system reboot and hiding.

Comment: Yes I understand that you would like that, but that is simply not possible in iOS as Apple won't let you run code on system reboot

Comment: I run this application is OSX.

Comment: What kind of shady thing were even trying to write? Running at midnight is very useful. Running something while making it completely hidden is pretty suspicious.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No timer needed. Observe the notification

```
static let NSCalendarDayChanged: NSNotification.Name
```

> Posted whenever the calendar day of the system changes, as determined by the system calendar, locale, and time zone. This notification does not provide an object.

> If the the device is asleep when the day changes, this notification will be posted on wakeup. Only one notification will be posted on wakeup if the device has been asleep for multiple days.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(calendarDayDidChange), name:.NSCalendarDayChanged, object:nil)

...

func calendarDayDidChange()
{
    print("day did change")
}
```

Or with the closure based API

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .NSCalendarDayChanged, object: nil, queue: .main) { _ in
   print("day did change")
}
```

Or with Combine

```
var subscription : AnyCancellable?

subscription = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSCalendarDayChanged)
    .sink { _ in print("day did change") }
```

Or with async/await (Swift 5.5+)

```
Task {
    for await _ in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: .NSCalendarDayChanged) {
        print("day did change")
    }
}
```

Comment: why didn't you finish your declaration with an initializer for the Notification.Name object?