# How do I automatically append a value to an array at the end of each day?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am working on a calorie tracking app where the user inputs values to keep a running calorie total throughout the day.  I would like to automatically append this daily value to an array at the end of each day so I can present running averages for the last seven days, fourteen days, and thirty days from the array data.

This seems like a straightforward enough issue, but I've been having trouble finding an answer or relevant example on here or googling in general.  Thanks in advance for any assistance or relevant links.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973888/run-code-at-midnight-everyday

Comment: Just maintain the date record while saving calories burnt in Struct , when the date is changed update the value of struct that store Total calories burnt and date to be compared with new date

Answer (score 2):

Don't append the value at the end of the day, append it the first time someone performs an action on the next day. You can use Date() to work out what day it is. If the day has changed since the last input then append the previous totals to the array.